# How to guarantee that a certain polynomial has all its zeros in the unit Disk

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

I am considering two polynomials with real coefficients $P$ and $Q$ such that $\deg P<\deg Q$ and we assume that **all** the zeros of $Q$ belong to the open unit disk $D(0,1)$.

Let $$\lambda = \inf\left\{\frac{|Q(e^{it})|}{|P(e^{it})|}:t\in\mathbb{R}\right\}>0$$
By Rouché’s theorem if $\alpha\in(-\lambda,\lambda)$ and $m$ is a nonnegative integer, then we have
$$\forall\,t\in\mathbb{R},\quad
|\alpha| |P(e^{it})|<|e^{imt}Q(e^{it})|.$$
Consequently, the polynomial $R_{\alpha,m}\triangleq X^m Q(X)-\alpha P(X)$ has all its zeros in $D(0,1)$.

Now, consider the set
$$A_m=\{\alpha\in \mathbb{R}:R_{\alpha,m}\hbox{ has all its zeros in $D(0,1)$}\}$$
We know that $A_m$ contains $(-\lambda,\lambda)$. But my question is the following:
Is $A_m$ an interval for $m\ge m_0$ for some $m_0$? (preferably $m_0=0$.)

Comment: Can we have a little more context to this? It sounds interesting so I am curious about its context.

Comment: Rouché's theorem doesn't give the obvious, centered inequality, but rather the "consequently" statement.

Comment: Have you figured out the answer when $P \equiv 1$?

Comment: @mathworker21 I do not think that the case you think of is any simpler.